# Import netCDF file to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, netcdf

Merry Christmas!  I am still very new to Python and Pandas, so any help is appreciated. I am trying to read in a netCDF file, which I can do and then import that into a Pandas Dataframe.  The netcDF file is 2D so I just want to 'dump it in'.  I have tried the DataFrame method but it doesn't recognize the object.  Presumably I need to convert the netCDF object to a 2D numpy array?  Again, thanks for any ideas on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 61):

The [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/) library handles arbitrary-dimensional netCDF data, and retains metadata. Xarray provides a simple method of opening netCDF files, and converting them to pandas dataframes:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('/path/to/netcdf')
df = ds.to_dataframe()
```

This will create a dataframe with a multi-index with all of the dimensions in it. Unfortunately, Pandas doesn't support arbitrary metadata, so that will be lost in the conversion, but you can keep the `ds` around, and use the metadata from that.

Answer (score 20):

If your NetCDF file (or [`OPeNDAP`](https://www.opendap.org/) dataset) follows CF Metadata conventions you can take advantage of them by using the [`NetCDF4-Python package`](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/), which makes accessing them in Pandas really easy.  (I'm using the Enthought Python Distribution which includes both Pandas and NetCDF4-Python).

In the example below, the NetCDF file is being served via OPeNDAP, and the NetCDF4-Python library lets you open and work with a remote OPeNDAP dataset just as if it was a local NetCDF file, which is pretty slick.  If you want to see the attributes of the NetCDF4 file, point your browser at this link http://geoport-dev.whoi.edu/thredds/dodsC/HUDSON_SVALLEY/5951adc-a1h.nc.html

You should be able to run this without changes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4

url='http://geoport-dev.whoi.edu/thredds/dodsC/HUDSON_SVALLEY/5951adc-a1h.nc'
vname = 'Tx_1211'
station = 0

nc = netCDF4.Dataset(url)
h = nc.variables[vname]
times = nc.variables['time']
jd = netCDF4.num2date(times[:],times.units)
hs = pd.Series(h[:,station],index=jd)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
hs.plot(ax=ax,title='%s at %s' % (h.long_name,nc.id))
ax.set_ylabel(h.units)
```

The result may be seen here in the Ipython Notebook: 
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4615153/

Answer (score 4):

You can use a library like PyNIO to read your file into p.e. numpy arrays and feed them to pandas.
[PyNIO](http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Nio.shtml) allows reading several file formats including classic netCDF3 and netCDF4.
[netcdf4-python](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python) can also read these netCDF formats and is py3.3 compatible

Comment: How do you save a grib object into a .grib extension file ? (the grib object being on the jupyter notebook)