# Store netCDF data in GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, python-xarray, geopandas, shapely, netcdf4

I need to perform some geometric operations with geometries from another source on a netCDF-file. Therefore I store the geometries (`shapely.geometry.Polygon`) from the other source in a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`.

Next is to read a `netCDF` file into a `GeoDataFrame`. The recipe seems clear: read the `netCDF` with `xarray`, store it into a `pandas.DataFrame`, perform a `shapely.geometry.Point` operation on the extracted lat/lon data and convert it into a `GeoDataFrame`.

Afterwards, I will do some statistics with geometry-operators.

---

When I read the `netCDF` file with `xarray` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035148/import-netcdf-file-to-pandas-dataframe))

```
import xarray as xr
dnc = xr.open_dataset(ff)  
df = dnc.to_dataframe()
```

I get

```
>>>> dnc   
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 16801, lon: 19201)
Coordinates:
   * lat      (lat) float32 -32.0 -31.9992 -31.9983 -31.9975 -31.9967 ...
   * lon      (lon) float32 -73.0 -72.9992 -72.9983 -72.9975 -72.9967 ...
Data variables:  
     hgt      (lat, lon) int16 0 0 0 4 0 5 0 9 9 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

>>> dnc.hgt.size
322596001
>>> dnc.lat.size
16801
>>> dnc.lon.size
19201
```

and

```
>>> df.head()
                  hgt   
lat   lon                  
-32.0 -73.000000    0  
      -72.999168    0  
      -72.998337    0  
      -72.997498    4  
      -72.996666    0
```

In `df` there is no access on `lat`and `lon`. I also have problems to understand the *partially* empty column `lat`. So I think that the `shapely.geometry.Point((lon, lat))` must be performed on `dnc` for every combination of `lon` and `lat`. Is that right? Any ideas how to code it?

Comment: The index in your `df` is a `Pandas.MultiIndex`. There are a bunch of ways to do this, try `df.reset_index()` to start.

Answer (score 3):

Like @jhamman mentioned in the comments, your lats and lons are indexes in your pandas frame.  So starting with that

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO('''             
    lat,lon,hgt                  
    -32.0,-73.000000,0  
    -32.0,-72.999168,0  
    -32.0,-72.998337,0  
    -32.0,-72.997498,4  
    -32.0,-72.996666,0
    ''')

    df = pd.read_csv(s)
    df = df.set_index(['lat', 'lon'])
```

We'll first reset the frame's index

`df = df.reset_index()`

then we'll create our geometry. i.e. shapely points with a list comp

`geom = [Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['lon'], df['lat'])]`

and now we convert our Pandas DataFrame to a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geom)
print(gdf.head())
    lat        lon  hgt                                          geometry
0 -32.0 -73.000000                      0                 POINT (-73 -32)
1 -32.0 -72.999168                      0  POINT (-72.99916800000001 -32)
2 -32.0 -72.998337                      0  POINT (-72.99833700000001 -32)
3 -32.0 -72.997498                      4  POINT (-72.99749799999999 -32)
4 -32.0 -72.996666                      0          POINT (-72.996666 -32)
```

Comment: Thanks @bob-haffner, @jhamman, `df.reset_index()` worked well. The huge amount of data made the computer swapping while resetting the index. I will work on the geom-operation next week and give feedback.

Comment: Ok, perhaps there's a way to avoid the reset by changing the way the dataframe is created (xarray.Dataset -> DataFrame) so that it doesn't set lat, lon as the index in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It took me even longer to try some solutions for my swapping memory (8 GB). At last I tried `dask`, but my approach is still not the right one:

```
for f in nc_files:
ff = os.path.join(nc_path, f)
try:
    dnc = xr.open_dataset(ff, chunks={'lat': 400, 'lon': 400})
    df = dnc.to_dataframe()
    df = df.reset_index()
    geom = [Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['lon'], df['lat'])]
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geom)
    print(gdf.head())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

As mentioned above, the files are big:

```
>>> dnc.hgt.size
322596001
>>> dnc.lat.size
16801
>>> dnc.lon.size
19201
```

Is there another approach to create a `geometry.Point` directly from the `netCDF-File`?