# Batch export of variables from netCDF4 files to .csv format

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export, netcdf4

I have selected multiple netCDF4 files from my folder.I need to convert selected variables from all such files to `.csv` format by looping.

Can you suggest me some ways to do such conversion
I have created a dataframe and tried tio export using this conversion

```
d=np.dstack((dtime,lat,lon,alt,range_ku,model_dry_tropo_corr,rad_wet_tropo_corr,iono_corr_alt_ku,sea_state_bias_ku,mean_sea_surface,solid_earth_tide,pole_tide))
#print(d)
df=pd.DataFrame(d[0,:], columns = ['dtime','lat','lon','alt','range_ku','model_dry_tropo_corr','rad_wet_tropo_corr','iono_corr_alt_ku','sea_state_bias_ku','mean_sea_surface','solid_earth_tide','pole_tide'])
#print(df)
df.to_csv("F:/data/New folder/"+file1.split('\\')[1][:-3]+".csv")
```

Comment: I would suggest to read the NetCDF file with Xarray, convert it to a Pandas dataframe, and let Pandas export it to CSV files. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035148/import-netcdf-file-to-pandas-dataframe and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: p.s. possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359869/convert-netcdf-file-to-csv-or-text-using-python

Comment: Yeah!I have created pandas dataframe for my file.But I feel difficulty in exporting all files at same time.

Comment: Can you edit/update your question with the new code you wrote?